# Scipy.linalg.qr_update doesn't work

Tags: python, scipy

Can't get why scipy.linalg.qr_update doesn't work properly.
From scipy documentation:

> qr_update(Q, R, u, v, overwrite_qruv=False, check_finite=True)
>
> If A = Q R is the QR factorization of A, return the QR factorization
>   of A + u vˆT for real A or A + u vˆH for complex A.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_update.html

But it doesn't work! Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *

N = 3
coef = 0.5
Q = np.eye(N)
R = coef * np.eye(N)
u  = np.matrix([[ 1.92981364,  0.2505024,   1.25051418]])

print "What should be:"
print Q*R + u.T * u

q1, r1 = qr_update(Q, R, u.T, u.T)

print "What we have:"
print q1 * r1
```

Output:

```
What should be:
[[ 4.22418069  0.48342295  2.41325932]
[ 0.48342295  0.56275145  0.3132568 ]
[ 2.41325932  0.3132568   2.06378571]]

What we have:
[[  4.22418069e+00  -7.36996838e-02  -1.53468755e+00]
[  0.00000000e+00   5.00656362e-01  -2.62290295e-03]
[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   5.16088504e-01]]
```

I would be grateful for any help you can give me!

Comment: be careful not to confuse `*` with matrix-multiplication/dot product. For normal numpy arrays `*` is element-wise. so `np.dot(A,B)` and `A*B` in general are not the same!

Comment: You are absolutely right - thank you!

print np.matrix(q1) * np.matrix(r1)

-gives the right answer